# Function, struct or class?

Tags: class, struct

I am trying to learn more about arduino programming, and recently i've written functions for randomizing and then modifying a single array. Now i'd like to do the same for four individual arrays. This is where i'm getting stuck. My questions:

Am i right to assume that it's not possible calling a function for multiple individual arrays?

Perhaps a separate question, but if a class or struct would be more suitable for multiple instances, what are the major differences worth considering to choose the right approach?

Comment: Use arrays. You can pass arrays to functions. On what is more suitable, it depends on what you want to do. In real life, arrays rarely exists by themselves. You can use a `struct` to group an array and its related data, and a `class` if you want to tie array, related data **and** functions in one package.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! Just to make sure we're on the same page: by individual arrays i mean that the four arrays all have different elements (If i'm not mistaken this implies individually declared arrays, no?). I've tried to read up on this, but i can't seem to come up with a solution where the same function returns four separately declared arrays, each with different elements. I'd be happy for a suggestion that points me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to use the same function for different arrays at different times, or are you trying to use a function that handles four different arrays at the same time?

If the former, you'd write something like

```
void myfunc( T *arr, size_t size ) // where T is the type of the array
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    arr[i] = some_new_value();
}
```

then call it for each array:

```
T arr1[N];  // where T is int, float, double, whatever
T arr2[M];
T arr3[O];
T arr4[P];

myFunc( arr1, N );
myFunc( arr2, M );
myFunc( arr3, O );
myFunc( arr4, P );
```

This assumes all the arrays have the same base type (e.g., they're all arrays of `int`).

If you want a function to work on four arrays simultaneously, you'd write it as

```
void myFunc( T *a1, size_t a1_size,
             T *a2, size_t a2_size,
             T *a3, size_t a3_size,
             T *a4, size_t a4_size )
{
  // code for handling each array
}
```

While I wrote it such that all the arrays have the same type, it doesn't have to be this way.  Each array can be a different type (`a1` can be `int`, `a2` can be `double`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

> Am i right to assume that it's not possible calling a function for multiple individual arrays?

What would give you that impression?  An array is just a pointer to a block of memory - as such it's just a variable. You can pass as many as you like to a function.

Just remember that a function can't know how big the array is that you pass it, since it only gets the pointer to the start of the array, so you need to pass the size of the array with it. You can't rely on the `sizeof` operator, since that is a compile-time directive that gives the size of a variable, which inside the function will be the size of a pointer (2 bytes on an 8 bit system). It can only give the size of an array (and then only the memory size in bytes, not the count of elements) if its run in the same (or a subordinate) scope as the declaration of the array.

> Perhaps a separate question, but if a class or struct would be more suitable for multiple instances, what are the major differences worth considering to choose the right approach?

A struct is just a way of grouping variables into compound types. Think of them as database records. Great for if you want to keep related, but different, information together in one block.  Classes are the same thing but add functions as well.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>* That's a very simplistic description. In actuality you can have functions in structs and not have functions in classes. The real difference between them is how access controls (private/protected/public) are implemented (there is none in structs, and they are all there in classes) and how inheritance / polymorphism works.</sup>

Comment: Regarding your first question: I can't figure out a way to pass four individually declared arrays to the same function, and figured i'd ask beforehand instead of trying something that in fact is impossible. If it's doable, please elaborate. Also, thanks for describing things in the latter part of your answer.

Comment: @Erik I can't unless you show us what it actually is you are trying to do.

Comment: "An array is just a pointer to a block of memory" - if we're talking about C or C++, this isn't correct.  Array *expressions* will be converted ("decay") to pointer expressions in most contexts, but array *objects* are not pointers.  An array is simply a contiguous sequence of elements - no storage is set aside for a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @JohnBode What on earth is an array *object*?

Comment: @Majenko: The memory set aside for the array elements.

Comment: @JohnBode That is just memory. There's nothing object-y about it. If it's local to a function it's just a change in the stack pointer. If it's global or static it's a chunk of memory in the BSS or .data section. All you get is a pointer to that block of memory. The array knows nothing about it. The size of an array is only ever known at compile time by the compiler.

Comment: @Majenko - I'm using the term "object" the same way that the C language definition uses "object" - a region of storage in the execution environment that may store values.  An array is *not* a pointer to a block of memory - an array *is* that block of memory.

Comment: @JohnBode The abstract concept of an array may be the memory, but the actual variable that you have in your program is a pointer. Can you add an integer to an array? No. Can you add an integer to a pointer? Yes.

Comment: @Majenko: No, the actual variable is *not a pointer*.  That's the point I'm trying to make.  The actual variable *is an array*.  No pointer value is stored in the memory referenced by the array name.

Comment: @JohnBode So... if you add 1 to an "array" variable, what do you get? I think the difference you are trying to get across is that an array is the address of a block of memory, but a pointer is a variable that contains the address of a block of memory. Either way both are variables that point to a block of memory. The compiler knows more about what the "array" style is pointing to (since it can see that in the source code) but when compiled both pure pointers (char *) and "arrays" (char[...]) are the same thing.

Comment: @Majenko: *An array is not an address*.  An array is a sequence of elements.  An array *expression* gets converted to a pointer expression as necessary, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnBode So - if you print an array, what do you get? Do you get the array, or do you get an address? Me, I get an address. There is no variable type in C that can store more than a simple number. Everything else is an address (a simple number) to a block of memory over which the compiler overlays an abstract concept. You're confusing abstract concepts and data storage.

Comment: @JohnBode This is why you can never pass a copy of an array to a function, and you can never return an array from a function. The array doesn't exist. Only the address.

Comment: @Majenko: Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  When you pass an array expression as an argument to a function (such as to `printf`), what the function receives is a pointer.  But the array *itself* is not a pointer.

Comment: @Majenko - This is why the expressions `arr` and `&arr` yield the same *value* (the address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array), but why the *types* are different (`T *` vs. `T (*)[N]`).

Comment: @Majenko: And this is why `sizeof` behaves differently for expressions of array type vs. expressions of pointer type.

Comment: @JohnBode You're still talking abstract concepts overlaid by the compiler. All those things you mention are compile-time constants. Things it can reference in the source code. As soon as it's compiled all those things vanish and are reduced to mere numbers. All you ever have, even if you call a block of memory an "array" and overlay some concept over it, is an address, and maybe a size if specified in the source code and the scope is suitable. No matter what you call an array, it's still a block of memory at an address, and, as you yourself said:

Comment: "the expressions arr and &arr yield the same value (the address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array)" - the "array" is just an address in memory.

Comment: “_As soon as it's compiled_” you are right. But if you write your code in C, rather than assembly, understanding the difference between an array and a pointer – and the related concept of pointer _decay_ – doesn't hurt.